What is the source of the intense blue colour of ultramarine pigment?
The pigment ultramarine was once a rare, expensive and highly prized pigment for artists because of its intense, long lasting blue colour. It was one of the most expensive pigments used in renaissance art.
Until the early 19th century invention of a synthetic source it was made only from the rare mineral lazurite (the blue component of lapis lazuli).
But what is the chemical or structural source of the intense blue colour?

The intense blue color of natural ultramarine pigment is due to the presence of polysulfide (S3-) radical anions within the mineral structure of lazurite, the blue component of lapis lazuli.

The blue color of ultramarine is due to the absorption of orange light Ultramarine largely consists of powdered lazurite
The crystal structure of Lazurite Contains thiozonide anions which have a strong absorption band in the orange part of the spectrum , leaving a blue color

@Harrychink So what is the key source of colour in thiazonide anions? And can they exist outside the mineral?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultramarine#Structure_and_classification
